# Loading text as a string, then extracting items

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement

My task is to write a .sh script that will load the user's first name. Then it will use a loop to count the occurrences of the letter 'a' and then print their number.

I understand that it is loading the text:
read / p "Please enter some text" text

Only then referring to the element $ {text [0]} gets all the text, not its single element

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please write"
read b
if [ ${b:${#b}-1:1} -eq 'a' ] ; then
 echo "Women"
else
echo "man"
fi

l=0
for (( i=0 ; i< ${#b} ; i++ )) do
if [ ${b:$i:1} -eq 'a' ] ; then
((l++))
fi

done

echo L = $l
```

Comment: `eq` should be `=`

Comment: Always quote your variables.

Comment: Use shellcheck.net to validate your syntax.

Comment: Thank you, it was enough to change -eq to ==

Answer (score 1):

For counting the number of `a` characters in a variable, you could erase first all characters which are not an *a*. Example:

```
text=abcaagg
atext=${text//[!a]/}
```

The variable `atext` now holds only `aaa`. Calculate the length of that string, and you know how many *a*  you had in your original variable:

```
echo ${#atext}
```

**UPDATE**: By request, I quote here the part of the bash man page which eplains the substitution. It is stated in the section titled *Parameter Expansion*:

> ```
>    ${parameter/pattern/string}
> ```

```
          Pattern substitution.  The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern
          just as in pathname expansion.  Parameter is expanded and the long‐
          est match of pattern against its value is replaced with string.  If
          pattern  begins  with  /,  all matches of pattern are replaced with
          string.  Normally only the first match is replaced.  If pattern be‐
          gins  with  #, it must match at the beginning of the expanded value
          of parameter.  If pattern begins with %, it must match at  the  end
          of  the expanded value of parameter.  If string is null, matches of
          pattern are deleted and the / following pattern may be omitted.  If
          the  nocasematch  shell  option  is enabled, the match is performed
          without regard to the case of alphabetic characters.
```

Comment: @Fravadona : Accepted! Actually, I feared that, when doing this interactively, the parser would interpret the `!` as a start of a history expansion expression, but I just verified that this is not the case. Aside from this, I don't think that emphasizing the difference to regexes is so important: After all it is clear from the language definition that we have a glob pattern here. If I'm not mistaken, the **only** place a regex can show up in bash, is to the right of the `=~` operator.

Comment: You could explain how the syntax of this regular expression works.


variable // expression / 
Is this how it works?

Comment: @czitak : There is no regular expression involved, but I sure can add an explanation.